# How to use "cookie-session" for keep the user logged-in in a Flutter Web application?

Tags: flutter, authentication, cookies, jwt

I am trying to set a JSON web token as a cookie in the back-end server, and use it inside the Flutter web front-end application to keep the user logged-in while the JWT is not expired.

I added `cookie-session` to my NodeJS app like following:

```
import cookieSession from "cookie-session";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    signed: false,
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60  // 1 hour
  })
);

app.use(signinRouter);
```

And inside `sign-in` route I used `req.session` to set the cookie-session` like below:

```
  const user_jwt = jwt.sign(
    {user_id : fromBinaryUUID(existingUser.id)},
    process.env.JWT_KEY!,
    {
      expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
    }
  );

  req.session = {
    jwt: user_jwt,
  };
```

And when I check the response data in the Chrome browser I see the following in the response header:

> jwt=eyJqd3QiOiJleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVekkxTmlJc0luUjVjQ0k2SWtwWFZDSjkuZXlelBpN3dqal9QT0FkSnpGNTQifQ==;
> path=/; expires=Tue, 11 Apr 2023 01:26:06 GMT; httponly

Now I want to use this token to keep the user logged-in after refreshing the chrome page in my Flutter web application, but don't know how?